# Linting to enforce PEP-585

Tags: python, mypy, python-3.9, python-typing, pep585

I'd like to be able to run some linting that fails if my code uses

```
from typing import List
x: List[str]
```

instead of

```
x: list[str]
```

for example.

I currently use mypy, so ideally there'd be some way to achieve this with that.

Comment: requesting tools is off topic as it attracts off-site and opinionated answers (for example, I'd shill my own `pyupgrade` which autofixes these, or potentially some flake8 plugins to check them)